# KIVY: How to know if the user has scrolled all the way down in a ScrollView?

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I have a big set of data and I want to load more data only when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the loaded list. I'm looking at the docs but I can't find anything... Any ideas? I'm using a recycle view inside a scrollview if that helps.

Comment: That's the problem that a `RecycleView` is intended to handle. How big is your big set of data?

Comment: yes, I'm using recycle view but I need to tell it what to load and when... that's my issue... how do I know the user has reached the bottom to load the next set of items? My data is about ~2 million lines with 50-100 characters per line

Comment: The `RecycleView` extends `ScrollView`, so you should be able to access the `scroll_y` property of the `RecycleView`.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you.